# how to mark a user as offline when the user close browser or tab without sign off

Tags: angular, websocket

I am using angular and websocket. when users login, I update database by using websocket message. However, it is not clear how to handle the offline status because users might just close the browser of tab without logging off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for your reference. I  have used Jquery and calling logout.aspx when browser will close the method call in logout.aspx and will update. You can use your  method.

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "logout.aspx",
        });
    });
});
```